# How can I prepare a shell environment before launching visual studio code on OS X?

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code

All the methods I've found for launching VS Code on a mac effectively launch it using the login shell environment. This includes the 'code' script and OSX's 'open' command.

I work with sandboxes (shell environments with different search path values, etc...) and want to start VS Code inheriting a particular sandbox's environment so it picks up those values; Most notably, the path to node and npm but also the myriad of supporting environment variables the applications require.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `launchctl` like described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152294/shell-environment-variables-not-available-in-gui-apps-even-if-app-launched-via-c)

Comment: I did.  This command seems to be modifying my search path ($PATH) by prepending system directories (eg. /iusr/local/bin).  It's finding node & npm there.